# Как получить значение из строки сжатой форматом данных DEFLATE

Tags: java, android, gzip, deflate

Как получить значение из строчки сжатой форматом данных DEFLATE, и как определить, что строчка является DEFLATE сжатой?

Также если кто-то начел писать до поправки (`gzip` тоже требуется)

Comment: У gzip может быть заголовок 0x1f, 0x8b. Но более надежный способ - проверить декомпрессию по данным и если не будет ошибок - можно считать что там был gzip. Получение же данных делается при помощи функции декомпрессии.

Comment: Для zlib все то же самое, только заголовки другие (см. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050260/what-does-a-zlib-header-look-like)

Answer (score 2):

Импортируете `DeflaterInputStream`/`GZIPInputStream` из пространства `java.util.zip`, создайте его экземпляр, указав поток с пожатыми входными данными, ну и дальше стандартно:

```
DeflaterInputStream deflaterInputStream = new DeflaterInputStream(inputStream);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*4];
int bytesRead = 0;

while ((bytesRead = deflaterInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Для проверки лучше всего пробовать распаковать небольшой кусок - если распаковывается, то значит сжато, не распаковывается - не сжато или повреждено.

**Обновление**

Сжатые данные должны приходить в виде потока ввода. Если это не так, то вероятно в каком-то коде у вас происходит преобразование потока ввода в строку, и по хорошему от этого следует избавится. Если нет возможности изменить код от которого вы получаете сжатые данные, то да, вам прийдется обратно преобразовывать строку в входной поток. Поэтому и желательно не тупо проверять первые байты, а именно брать небольшой кусок в сотню-другую килобайт, да проверять корректность его распаковки.

Comment: Строчка приходит в виде String, а у вас байты, так должно быть? или надо переводить string в byte, и не очень понятны многие вещи в скрипте, что такое 1024*4, и как работает while

Comment: Единицы байт могут быть расшифрованы корректно даже при подаче мусора не вход.

Comment: не понел так что пихать в inputStream

Comment: Есть переменная String, приходит из httpclient,  она deflate, мне надо этот deflate перевести в текст

Comment: И это строчка в utf-8

Comment: И также что такое outputStream, я догадатся сам не могу, можно функцию которая все это делает?

Comment: Нашел код, но он в начале сжимает строчку потом ее расжимает, и получается что входные данные проходят через сжатие и разжатие и в итоге выходят входные данные, но как его сделать чтобы он принемал входные данные и расжимал их, вот код http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/zip/Deflater.java#Deflater

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, из Google'овского или Apache'вского HttpClient'а приходят данные? И у того, и у другого все основные методы возвращают потоки. Да, есть методы возвращающие строки, но они - просто обертки для удобства. Насчет разжатия - оба этих клиента умеют автоматически распаковывать сжатые при помощи gzip/deflate ответы, при корректно установленном сервером заголовке `Content-Encoding`, и соответствующей включенной опции хендлера. Если же у вас какой-то хитрый HttpClient, то всё равно рекомендую глянуть в заголовок ответа `Content-Encoding` -  вероятно там указанно применявшееся сжатие

Comment: У меня обычный HttpClient, он отсылает определенные пост запросы в utf-8 и получает ответ в виде string, я не замечал чтобы он разбирал заголовки сервера, попробую, если получится через заголовок то это многое решит,

Comment: Наладил заголовки, браузер на них реагирует отлично, а httpclient не хочет их принемать. Используется import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

Comment: Улучшил теперь используется HttpURLConnection, но deflate сново не работает